# Smart Capture form: adding a 'free-form / please specify' option to multiple choice question

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

We would like to avoid coding a custom form with a custom cloud page, and use SFMC's Smart Capture functionality since we've got a rather simple requirement (collect order quantities and titles of our customers on a simple form). Now, I'm aware that in a multiple-choice question (radio-button or otherwise) scenario, smart capture does not provide a built-in option  of adding a "free-form / please specify" option at the end. I was wondering can we add this option "manually", into the SmartCapture's built-in html code? And, if yes, is this going to be reflected in the target data extension?

Here's the html code of the SmartCapture (i.e. of the particular form field):

```
<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label">Title</div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input-wrapper">

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Title" data-field-type="Text" value="Manager">&nbsp;Manager</label></div>

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Title" data-field-type="Text" value="Director">&nbsp;Director</label></div>

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Title" data-field-type="Text" value="Owner">&nbsp;Owner</label></div>

 <div class="sc-formfield-input"><label><input type="checkbox" name="Title" data-field-type="Text" value="Executive">&nbsp;Executive</label></div>
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear. why do you want to explicitly define checkbox/ dropdown when you can do it by simply modifying the smart capture field properties.

Comment: If you decide that a field will be a checkbox, you cannot add that the last among the choices will be a free-form (type: text) question. So, if a contact cannot find his/her position among those on offer, he/she cam write down its role. Also, this is a mandatory question, so it cant be skipped.